# Adjust opus bit rate in Mozilla Firefox - WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, mozilla, opus

I just read an article from this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/WebRTC_codecs

I want to know if there's a way on how to manually or programmatically adjust the default 48 kbps to 8 kbps? I am currently working on WebRTC and I need to use the narrowband (NB) for my webphone.

[image]

Another article: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/firefox-beta-15-supports-the-new-opus-audio-format/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the SDP from the browser's offer,
pass that SDP to the following function and it will return you a modified SDP with your desired audio bitrate set:

function onCreateOfferSuccess(desc) {
desc.sdp = setAudioBitrate(desc.sdp, 8, true);
}

```
function setAudioBitrate(sdp, bitrate, isFirefox) {
var modifier = "b=AS:";
if (isFirefox) {
    bitrate = (bitrate >>> 0) * 1000;
    modifier = "b=TIAS:";
}

var lines = sdp.split("\r\n");
var line = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].indexOf("m=audio") === 0) {
        line = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (line === -1)
    return sdp;

// Pass the m line
line++;

// Skip i and c lines
while (lines[line].indexOf("i=") === 0 || lines[line].indexOf("c=") === 0)
    line++;

// If we are on a b line, replace it
if (lines[line].indexOf("b") === 0) {
    lines[line] = modifier + bitrate;
    return lines.join("\r\n");
}

// Add a new b line
var newLines = lines.slice(0, line);
newLines.push(modifier + bitrate);
newLines = newLines.concat(lines.slice(line, lines.length));
return newLines.join("\r\n");
}
```